# AMP Analytics "destinationDomains" not working in Linker config

Tags: json, google-analytics, amp-html, gtag.js

I am trying to enable a linker string for links to my domains from my AMP site.

The current config is working only for links to the "canonical" domain at present, which is the default behavior.

I am also trying to enable it for links that are sent to my app's domain.

I've tried many variations of the code below (including using non-valid JSON array strings, as set out in the documentation here: https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/joining_analytics_sessions/#destination-domains) however this does not seem to work.

I am hoping this is a syntax or config issue but I am starting to have doubts. This is my code:

```
<amp-analytics type="gtag" data-credentials="include">
<script type="application/json">
{
   "vars": {
      "gtag_id": "AW-XXXXXX",
      "config": {
         "UA-XXXXX-X": {
            "groups": "default"
         },
         "AW-XXXXXX": {
            "groups": "default"
         }
      }
   },
   "linkers": {
     "enabled": true,
     "proxyOnly": false,
     "destinationDomains": [ "amp.mydomain.com", "www.mydomain.com", "app.altdomain.ly" ]
   },
   "triggers": {
      "trackPageview": {
         "on": "visible",
         "request": "pageview"
      }
   }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

I've also tried setting it out with a nested `<paramName>` object as follows, but I get the same result (works on canonical only):

```
...
    "linkers": {
        "Linker1": {
            "ids": {
                "_cid": "CLIENT_ID"
            },
            "proxyOnly": false,
            "destinationDomains": [ "amp.mydomain.com", "www.mydomain.com", "app.altdomain.ly" ],
            "enabled": true
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using gtag, I think you might need to use the GTAG's configuration to configure the domains. Instructions are available [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/#link_domains).

Basically, the config looks like this:

```
<amp-analytics type="gtag" data-credentials="include">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars" : {
    "gtag_id": "<GA_TRACKING_ID>",
    "config" : {
      "<GA_TRACKING_ID>": {
        "groups": "default",
        "linker": { "domains": ["example.com", "example2.com"] }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check first the proper format of [`linkers`](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/linker-id-forwarding.md) in AMP:

```
"linkers": {
  <paramName>: {
    ids: <Object>,
    proxyOnly: <boolean>,
    destinationDomains: <Array<string>>,
    enabled: <boolean>
  }
}
```

> `paramName` - This user defined name determines the name of the query
>   parameter appended to the links.
>
> `ids` - An object containing key-value pairs that is partially encoded
>   and passed along in the param.
>
> `proxyOnly` - (optional) Flag indicating whether the links should only
>   be appended on pages served on a proxy origin. Defaults to true.
>
> `destinationDomains` - (optional) Links will be decorated if their
>   domains are included in this array. Defaults to canonical and source
>   domains.
>
> `enabled` - Publishers must explicity set this to true to opt-in to
>   using this feature.

This linker uses this configuration to generate a string in this structure: `<paramName>=<version>*<checkSum>*<idName1>*<idValue1>*<idName2>*<idValue2>...` For more details see [Linker Param Format](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/linker-id-receiving.md#Format).

Comment: Hi Jess, thanks for your response. My understanding from the AMP documentation is that the <paramName> nested object is optional, and you can set the default behavior at the level below? In any case, nesting it like this doesn't seem to work for me. Can you link to a working example?